# Was the anime faithful to the light novel?

Tags: muv-luv

Recently I finished watching Muv-Luv Alternative: Total Eclipse and was wondering. How faithful to the light novel was the anime? Are there any mayor deviations, or even minor ones? Or is it identical?

Comment: Both were both visual novel games before they were adapted into manga/anime. The novel are more or less an adaptation of the game. Are you referring to how faithful they were to the light novel series or the visual novel games (and manga)?

Comment: @Krazer Refering to both the novels in this case. visual novel  to manga/anime/light novel

Comment: @Krazer While Muv-Luv Alternative was originally a VN, Total Eclipse is originally a LN. Total Eclipse is a side story of Alternative with different characters. Thus the right question to ask in this case is how close the anime is to the LN.